# Constructor error when using FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am trying to use FirebaseListAdapter to create a ListView that contains product names, but I'm getting this error:

```
error: no suitable constructor found for
FirebaseListAdapter(MainActivity,Class<String>,int,Firebase) constructor
FirebaseListAdapter.FirebaseListAdapter(Activity,Class<String>,int,Query)
is not applicable
```

I have the latest version of Google Play Services and Google Repository as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

My build.gradle (root) is:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

and my build.gradle (app) is:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The code that I'm using is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Firebase firebase;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    firebase = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Firebase products = firebase.child("names");
    FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
        //
        }
    };
    }
}
```

I tried all the solutions that I found for similar issues, but no luck. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the new SDK:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
```

With the legacy SDK:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.1'
```

They are not compatible. Make this change:

```
//compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
```

And review the [Firebase Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) to get an understanding of the code changes needed.

If you don't need the capabilities  of the new SDK, then I suppose you could remove those dependencies and run with the legacy SDK.  I haven't tried that and don't know if you will encounter other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try that way:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, String model) {
    //
    }
};
```

FirebaseListAdapter populateView method has only two parameters and String.class, is twice.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. My error is: `Method does not override method from its superclass`. So, three parameters  are needed.

Comment: You can see [here](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseListAdapter.html)  must me two.

Comment: FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, /*String.class,*/ android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products). I think the second String.class must be deleted ;)

Comment: As i see, there are three constructors:
1. `FirebaseListAdapter(Activity activity, java.lang.Class<T> modelClass, int modelLayout, com.firebase.client.Firebase ref) `
2. `FirebaseListAdapter(Activity activity, java.lang.Class<T> modelClass, int modelLayout, com.firebase.client.Query ref) `
Each one has 4 arguments. If remove one, i have the same error.

Comment: Did you try to replace android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 with your own layout ;) look at [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580991/how-to-use-firebase-list-adapter)